# change css of currently active paragraph in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just realized how to make a div editable. Now i am trying to make a custom editor using the same.I already have made the contentEditable on the same. Now the problem that I am facing is I want to focus on just the current para `<p>` that the user is trying to change. For example in html the code is like

```
<div id = "editor">
    <p>
        this is first para
    </p>
    <p>
        this is second para
    </p>
</div>
```

Now what i want is if a user is editing the content inside the first p tag then the font color of the same should be black, and all other p content turned to light black.
How can i do this,also can it be done in pure `css` ?

Comment: Could you post your entire demo [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it completely by using CSS only. You'll need some JS as well. Here is a code snippet for the effect you are trying to apply.

```js
$('#editor2 p').click(function(){
  $('#editor2 p').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
p{
 color:blue;
}

#editor[contenteditable="true"] p{
 color: red;
}

#editor2[contenteditable="true"] p{
 color: green;
}

#editor2[contenteditable="true"] p.active{
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "editor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        this is first para
    </p>
    <p>
        this is second para
    </p>
</div>

<div id = "editor2" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        this is first para
    </p>
    <p>
        this is second para
    </p>
</div>
```